# Creating trigger based on multiple conditions in sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Dear amazing programmers,
I am trying to create `trigger` in my application database to delete rows in a table based on multiple condition and deletion in another table, and i could use some help here.

Here is my code for the `trigger`

```
CREATE TRIGGER RemoveAccountReports 
AFTER DELETE ON Accounts 
FOR EACH ROW 
WHEN Reports.Parent_Type = ACCOUNT 
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM Reports 
WHERE Parent_ID = OLD.Account_ID; 
END;
```

I need to delete from `Reports` table with every deletion in `Accounts` table where `Reports.Parent_ID = Accounts.Account_ID`.

But only if `Reports.Parent_type = "ACCOUNT"`

How can i achieve that ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that you are missing quotes around ACCOUNT; it should be:

`WHEN Reports.Parent_Type = 'ACCOUNT'`

(Note that single quotes should be used with strings.)

Comment: Great!  Please consider checking the accept button to accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

when you execute your statement you gonna have this error :

```
 no such column: Reports.Parent_Type
```

the Solution :

```
CREATE TRIGGER RemoveAccountReports 
AFTER DELETE ON Accounts 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
DELETE FROM Reports 
WHERE Parent_ID = OLD.Account_ID AND  Reports.Parent_Type = 'ACCOUNT' ; 
END;
```

Comment: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ACCOUNT (code 1): , while compiling: DELETE FROM Accounts WHERE Account_ID = 1

Comment: hey Please can you post your Class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper to see your Database Structutre and understand from where come this problem ?